# Sort a dictionary by values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary like so:

```
   dic = {"first_a" : { "first_b" : {10, 2} } , "second_a" : {"second_b" : {13, 15} } [...] }
```

I would like to sort the nested dictionary according to the sum of first_b and second_b values.
I can't get my head around this one, could someone provide an helping hand ?
I have tried to use the sorted() function but wasn't able to find the right lambda function to use as key..

Comment: could you supply a valid dictionary?  What are first_a, etc?

Comment: Please supply a meaningful (and valid) input and expected output.  At face value, it would be impossible to sort on the sums of x_a and y_a because those are dictionaries and cannot be added by the sum() function, so there is something missing or unclear in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you meant to have a dictionary like this:

```py
data = {'a': {'b': {2, 10}}, 'c': {'d': {13, 15}}}
```

You can get what you want like this:

```py
sorted(data, key =lambda k: sum(*dic[k].values()), reverse=True)
```

However I don't consider this very readable.  I would instead do:

```py
def get_sum(k):
    vals, *_ = data[k].values()
    return sum(vals)

sorted(data, key=get_sum, reverse=True)
```

When I'm looking at code late at night, too many parentheses == too long to figure out what's happening.

Note that I used `values()` because I didn't know if your inner keys were constant.  If they were, life is even easier.  Note this operates on and sorts the *keys*.